# Start R with commands R Studio

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio, blas

I use RStudio, it's fantastic. Recent adjustments to my BLAS installation, however, require me to start R with the command

```
taskset 0xffff R
```

To get parallel processing to work. Is there a way tell RStudio to start it's R session with this command so I can use RStudio with parallel?

(I know parallel and GUI's don't play that nice)

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm running kUbuntu.

Comment: Maybe the person who can answer you doesn't need this but it might help if you mention your OS and it can't hurt.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer to this (quite likely from the RStudio developers) in the RStudio forums: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by customizing your `Rprofile.site` file, as described here:

http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html